# Android: setRetainInstance bad practice for screen rotation?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know its possible to SetRetainInstance in a fragment so that when an activity is detroyed the fragmetn isn't destroyed with it. Then when the activity is recreated we can re attached the fragment. I see lots of people using this for screen rotation, but isn't this bad practice?

Or can we ignore this?

What is the ideal way of saving info between config changes if we can't use SetRetainInstance ?

I do have one query if I did use SetRetainInstance  in a fragment that means that it wouldn't get destroyed when the activity gets detroyed so how do we ensure that this activity doesn't get left behind ?

Is this a concern ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I know its possible to SetRetainInstance in a fragment so that when an
>   activity is detroyed the fragmetn isn't destroyed with it. Then when
>   the activity is recreated we can re attached the fragment. I see lots
>   of people using this for screen rotation, but isn't this bad practice?

No. What you are doing by re attaching the original fragment if it exists is avoiding creating a new instance every time the orientation changes.

> Or can we ignore this?

If you do, then you will unnecessarily be creating a new instance on every rotation.

> What is the ideal way of saving info between config changes if we
>   can't use SetRetainInstance ?

Depends on what kind on info you are trying to save. One way is to use onSavedInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState.

> I do have one query if I did use SetRetainInstance in a fragment that
>   means that it wouldn't get destroyed when the activity gets detroyed
>   so how do we ensure that this activity doesn't get left behind ?

onDetach and onDestroyView will be called in this case as well. You can clean up any views/activity references here.